How to hide the endpoints of a curve behind the vertices
Below is the code. We notice that the endpoints of two curves are covering the lines.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=0.8]
    \tikzset{vertex/.style = {circle, draw, fill={rgb,255: red,245; green,245; blue,245}, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt}}
    \tikzset{edge0/.style = {line width=1.2pt, black}}
    \tikzset{edge1/.style = {line width=1pt, blue, opacity=0.7}}
    
    \node [vertex] (v0) at (45:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (v1) at (135:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (v2) at (225:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (v3) at (315:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (w0) at (45:1) {};
    \node [vertex] (w1) at (135:1) {};
    \node [vertex] (w2) at (225:1) {};
    \node [vertex] (w3) at (315:1) {};
    
    % Move the problematic edges before the nodes to avoid covering
    \draw [edge1] plot[smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(v0) (135:3) (v2)};
    \draw [edge1] plot[smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(v1) (45:3) (v3)};
    
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{Mod(\i+1,4)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{Mod(\i+2,4)}
        \foreach \v in {v,w} {
            \draw [edge0] (\v\i) edge (\v\j) {};
        };
        \draw [edge0] (v\i) edge (w\i) {};
        \draw [edge1] (v\i) edge (w\j) {};
        \draw [edge1] (v\j) edge (w\i) {};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I noticed some similar issues and was advised not to use coordinates but instead use vertices. However, in this case, if I use the plot(plot[smooth, tension=0.7]) command, it seems unavoidable to use the coordinates option.

Putting the endpoints of a line segment "over" the line segment


As a workaround, you could use (v0.15), (v2.75), and so one. The plot handlers don't understand the concept of nodes. At least not out of the box. Another workaround would be to draw the circles later with fill=white.

You can create a very similar curve without plot and thus avoid the problem:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=0.8]
    \tikzset{vertex/.style = {circle, draw, fill={rgb,255: red,245; green,245; blue,245}, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt}}
    \tikzset{edge0/.style = {line width=1.2pt, black}}
    \tikzset{edge1/.style = {line width=1pt, blue, opacity=0.7}}
    
    \node [vertex] (v0) at (45:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (v1) at (135:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (v2) at (225:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (v3) at (315:2.5) {};
    \node [vertex] (w0) at (45:1) {};
    \node [vertex] (w1) at (135:1) {};
    \node [vertex] (w2) at (225:1) {};
    \node [vertex] (w3) at (315:1) {};
    
    % Move the problematic edges before the nodes to avoid covering
    \draw[edge1] (v1) to[in=70,out=20,looseness=2.1] (v3);
    
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{Mod(\i+1,4)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{Mod(\i+2,4)}
        \foreach \v in {v,w} {
            \draw [edge0] (\v\i) edge (\v\j) {};
        };
        \draw [edge0] (v\i) edge (w\i) {};
        \draw [edge1] (v\i) edge (w\j) {};
        \draw [edge1] (v\j) edge (w\i) {};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


